# Validation to model either this or that but must have one Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9.3

I have 3 Models

```
class Audio
end

class Album
end

class Movie
end
```

I want to have validation in Audio model.That while creating Audio the server should validate that the audio is linked with the album or movie or both. But both the fields selecting models in the from shouldn't be empty while submit.

Comment: You need to give us more info.  What fields are in your models? How are your models related? Are they nested. I think the answer to your question will in part depend on the design of your app.

Comment: I agree with diasks2. Seems that [AR Validations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) should give you enough info. You could also refer to [AR Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for how to relate models to each other.

Comment: Right now I am writing the model so they only have few fields like name and details and no association. and I want the association like audio belong to at least album or movie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Album should be linked with another type, lets say "Media". This allows you to have a field on "Media" which can be either "movie" or "audio".

Take a look at classy_enum on how to enforce the types:
https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum